# Blank screen on call to AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, screen

When I call to `asynctask` which is using for sending data to server,makes screen blank. I used lots of solutions given on the stack overflow..still not working :(....

Here is the code for `Asynctask class`

```
public class SendRequestToServer1 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        //AsyncTask<i/p type, , return type>
        Context mContext;

        private ProgressDialog dialog;

        public SendRequestToServer1(Context context){
//      public SendRequestToServer(Activity currentActivity){
            this.mContext = context;


        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(SampleClientMainFrame.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.show();

            super.onPreExecute();



        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);


        }

        //use thread for parallel/Network work

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //create HTTP client

            // Instantiate the custom HttpClient

            MyHttpClient mhc = new MyHttpClient();
            MyHttpClient.setContext(mContext);

            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(mhc.createClientConnectionManager(), client.getParams());

            //get/post, data modes eXml, auditLog, username password
            String getPost = params[0]; //get/post....get..post
            String dataMode = params[1]; //dataMode
            String uriString = params[2]; //UriString
            String DataToBeSent = params[3];//Aadhaar requests

            Log.d("###UriString", uriString);

            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uriString);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(uriString);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);

            if(getPost.equals("POST")){
                Log.d("In", "POST");
                if(dataMode.equals("eXml")){
                    Log.d("In", "eXml");

                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("eXml", DataToBeSent));

                    try {
                        //httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(signedXML));
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        Log.d("#UnsupportedEncodingException***", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }else {
                    try {
                        httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(DataToBeSent));
                        //httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                        Log.d("#UnsupportedEncodingException***", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }       

            // Making HTTP Request

            String responseXML = "";
            try {

                if(getPost.equals("POST")){
                    Log.d("In", "post");
                    HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httppost);

                    responseXML = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
                } else if(getPost.equals("GET")){
                    Log.d("In", "get");
                    HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(httpget);

                    responseXML = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
                }

                System.out.println("ResponseXml :"+responseXML);

//              Log.d("Response :", responseXML);

                return responseXML;

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                Log.d("Exc", "1Exception");
                Log.d("ClientProtocolException***", e.getMessage());
                return "#ClientProtocolException***"+e.getMessage();
                //e.printStackTrace();              
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                Log.d("Exc", "2Exception");
                Log.d("IOException***", e.getMessage());
                return "#IOException***"+e.getMessage();
                //e.printStackTrace();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.d("Exc", "3Exception");
                Log.d("Exception", e.getMessage());
                return "#Exception :"+e.getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how I call it...

```
try {
            //send request xml to the server
            responseXML =
                    new SendRequestToServer1(getApplicationContext()).execute("POST", "eXml", uriStr , signedXml).get();// get updated time
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            Log.d("Request", e.getMessage());
        }
```

Any help appreciated...

Comment: Code is fine.. Can't understand why its coming. Can you show your another classes code for activity.

Comment: this is my main activity...

Comment: Asynktask didn't really helped me. I used threads and job is done :)